# Is there any alternative to org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.isEmpty()?

Tags: java, collections, is-empty, null-check

It seems that org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils doesn't contain isEmpty() anymore.

Is there any other "common" library, which contains the same functionality?

Comment: Still there in 4.1:  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty(java.util.Collection)

Comment: Are you using Spring ? They have the same utility: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/CollectionUtils.html

Comment: How hard is it to write `collection != null && collection.size() == 0` yourself?

Comment: @cricket_007: Don't call `size()` ! That could be expensive. use `isEmpty()`.

Comment: @cricket_007 or use `collection.isEmpty()` ;)

Comment: @Thilo `isEmpty()` is clearer, few collections are much faster with isEmpty().

Answer (score -1):

The Problem was the version. Imported was 3.1, isEmpty() is from 3.2 available. Solution:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```